# characterization of measurable simple function

Tags: measure-theory

$\chi_{A} $ means characteristic function of set $A$. Consider a simple function 
$$s = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \chi_{A_i} $$
If all of $\lbrace A_i \rbrace_{i=1}^n $ are measurable sets then $s$ becomes measurable function. Does the converse also hold? I mean, if $s$ is a measurable set, then does that imply all of $\{   A_i \}_{i=1}^N $ are also measurable sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $s=1$, by which I mean

$$ s=\Bbb 1_N + \Bbb 1_{N^c}$$
where $N$ is a non-measurable set.

If you ask for $s$ to have a decomposition $∑_1^N a_i\Bbb 1_{A_i}$ where $A_i$ are maximally chosen sets i.e. $A_i = [s=a_i]$ then we do indeed have $A_i = s^{-1}(\{a_i\})$ are measurable sets.